# EF 6 - AsNoTracking() throws error -An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: entity-framework-6

Please find the below code works well in EF4.

```
  public IObjectSet<PositionVoyage> PositionVoyages
    {
        get 
        {           
            if (_positionVoyages == null)
            {
                var data = CreateObjectSet<PositionVoyage>("PositionVoyages");
                if (NoTracking)
                    data.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
                else
                    data.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;

                _positionVoyages = data;
            }
            return _positionVoyages;
        }       
    }
```

But When I upgrade to EF6 I'm following the below code:

```
 public IDbSet<PositionVoyage> PositionVoyages
    {
        get
        {

            if (_positionVoyages == null)
            {
                var data = Set<PositionVoyage>();
                var query = data.AsNoTracking();
                _positionVoyages = data;
            }

            return _positionVoyages;
        }

    }
```

Here I'm ending up with an error:

> "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker." when it reaches below line.
>
> Context.AttachTo(entitySetName, entity);

Please help me in this regards.

Thanks,
Dharma

Comment: This exception always means that an object is attached to more than one context instance at the same time (which throws this error if the entity is a dynamic proxy for lazy loading or change tracking). It can just mean that you load objects from different contexts (or attach it manually to different contexts) and relate them somehow in a single object graph, or it can be a problem with context lifetime management (for example, contexts are not properly disposed). But it's impossible to answer exactly without more code details.